# C# How to return to last step after performing goto statement?

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
private void Mymethod()
{
    if(animal == "Dog")
    {
        goto LabelMonsters;
    }

    //return here after goto LabelMonsters executes
    if (animal == "Cat")
    {
        goto LabelMonsters;
    }

    //another return here after goto LabelMonsters executes
    if (animal == "Bird")
    {
        goto LabelMonsters;
    }

    //Some long codes/execution here.
    return;

    LabelMonsters:
    //Some Code
}
```

In my sample i have several if statement, after performing goto statement for the first time, I must return to the next step under my method. I tried continue but not working. The execution must continue up to the end.

Comment: As a side note: you could use or(`||`) instead of three `if`.

Comment: You might want to have a look at "methods" or "functions". Those allow you to execute a sub-function and return back.

Comment: Learn to structure code without abusing goto? If you need to go backwards why not structure code in a way that code after the Label is before the return?

Comment: You should definitly avoid `goto` as it enforced spaghetti-code. Instead use methods and properties on classes.

Comment: i cant use || because i need some values in each of the condition. Even if i use ||, i still have a next step which is a different kind of execution.

Comment: I can't believe `goto` is still in c#

Comment: thanks guys. all i think there is some special kind of command that can return back to the last step after execution. i will rather use another methods under class

Comment: @KhawajaAtteeq I've found it useful on ***very** specific* situations (e.g. invoking other `case` in `switch` statements). Not that these couldn't be refactored into methods (and I have generally done, out of "fear" for gotos ;-) ), but some oneliners are ok IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short course in programming: DO NOT use goto.

For a fuller flavor, combine a [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) with a [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement:

```
 private void MyMethod()
 {
     switch (animal)
     {
         case "Dog":
         case "Cat":
         case "Bird":
            LabelMonster(animal);
            break;
     }

     // afterwards...
 }

 private void LabelMonster(string animal)
 {
     // do your animal thing
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't. `goto` is a one-way ticket. Although the use of `goto` *may* be "correct" in some situations, I'd say not in this one... why don't you do something like this instead?

```
private void LabelMonsters()
{
  // Some Code
}

private void Mymethod()
{
    if(animal=="Dog")
    {
        LabelMonsters();
    }
    if (animal=="Cat")
    {
        LabelMonsters();
    }
    if (animal == "Bird")
    {
        LabelMonsters();
    }
    // Some long codes/execution here.
}
```

Of course, this code would be equivalent:

```
private void Mymethod()
{
    if(animal=="Dog" || animal=="Cat" || animal == "Bird")
    {
        // Some code
    }
    // Some long codes/execution here.
}
```

but I won't take anything for granted, since I don't know what your code is doing (it could be changing `animal`)

Comment: i don't know if goto is correct in any situation :P

Comment: @StianStandahl I won't argue that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use a method?

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    if (animal == "Dog" || animal == "Cat" || animal == "Bird") LabelMonsters();
    //Code to run after LabelMonsters or if its not one of that animals
}
void LabelMonsters()
{
    //Your code
}
```